Should std::get<T&>(tuple) work for zip_view's output?
In short: std::get<T&>('tuple-like') does not work when using ranges library in MSVC, and I wonder what is expected according to the C++ standard.
I cannot get the code below to compile correctly on MSVC 19.40. It does work with both gcc and clang, though, and I am yet to find information that speaks in favour of MSVC's behaviour.
sample code
#include <tuple>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    using namespace std::views;

    char foo{};

    std::ranges::for_each(zip(iota(0, 2) | transform([&](int i) -> char& { return foo; })),
                          [] (auto t) { auto bar = std::get<char&>(t); });

    return 0;
}

error message
error C2039: '_Ttype': is not a member of 'std::_Tuple_element<_Ty,std::tuple<>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=char &
        ]

Should I expect std::get to work here, or am I missing something?

The issue seems to be related to using
std::ranges::for_each(..., [] (auto t) { ... });

i.e. with auto parameter. Simply replacing auto with std::tuple<char&> works. I am still unsure whether this behaviour is correct, but it does compile with all three compilers.
To make sure no unwanted tuple conversion was applied (i.e. std::tuple<char> <-> std::tuple<char&>), I replaced char foo{}; from the question with a no-copy-no-move structure
struct no_copy_move {
    no_copy_move() = default;
    no_copy_move(no_copy_move const&) = delete;
    no_copy_move(no_copy_move&&) = delete;
};
no_copy_move foo{};

and then changed the lambdas
[&](int i) -> char& { return foo; }
[] (auto t) { auto bar = std::get<char&>(t); }

to
[&](int i) -> no_copy_move& { return foo; }
[] (std::tuple<no_copy_move&> t) { auto& bar = std::get<no_copy_move&>(t); }

which also compiles.
TLDR
I do not know if std::get should work with auto parameter or not, but changing it to std::tuple<char&> works.

I believe that this is due to the implementation of P2609R3, which changes the constraints of for_each to effectively require the following to be valid:
iter_value_t<It> v = *it;
f(proj(v));

(where proj defaults to std::identity{}, which returns the argument unchanged)
When It is zip_view's iterator, iter_value_t<It> is std::tuple<char>, which doesn't support std::get<char&> because it doesn't have a char& element.
Thus, the lambda expression doesn't support f(proj(v)) which is required by P2609R3, and MSVC is correct to emit an error.
Also note that the same code does not work with latest gcc or latest clang: https://godbolt.org/z/3Pv71rY5z.

Thanks for input! I am happy to see that both clang and gcc reject it; I only tested up to gcc 14.2 and clang 19.1.0, but will make sure I also test trunk in the future.
That said, as I am a little behind on c++ linguistics, I do not really get P2609R3. But thanks to you I did some more testing, and in turn I now believe the root issue is related to argument deduction.  In short, I found that (std::tuple<char&> t) instead of (auto t) works: https://godbolt.org/z/vEd1sWEeP.
Does that speak in favour of or against your answer?

@ProbabilisticS Changing the parameter to std::tuple<char&> t works because std::tuple<char>& is convertible to std::tuple<char&>. That doesn't speak against my answer. Whether it's in favor -- your call.

Yes, that would explain it. I've had a bit of trouble using static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(t), ...>); inside the projection lambda to find the deduced type, and that got me wondering why. But back to your answer: does iter_value_t<It> v = *it; mean that there will always be copies (even though I output references from the transform), or would it be reasonable to expect compilers to by-pass it (as long as the type is copy'able, of course). It would make very little sense for me to explicitly specify a reference return type if the for_each gives me copies anyway.

The problem is - std defect or not - transform_view always returns by value, even if the projection function returns by reference. The workaround woud be to use something like std::reference_wrapper as the transformation result:
auto trv = my_view 
         | std::views::transform(
              [&](auto&&)
              { return std::ref(result);}
);
auto&& ref = trv.front().get();

In case of OP, the tuple type can change from current std::tuple<char> to std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<char>>:
auto ztv = zip( iota(0, 2)
         | transform(
              [&foo](int i)
              { return std::ref(foo); }));

The element type(std::reference_wrapper<char>) is long and counter-intuitive. Full accessor invocation would then become a double get:
auto&& bar=get<0>(t).get();

IMHO, the compulsory value return from transform is a std defect, but that requires another thread for language lawyers.

I've tested the following: https://godbolt.org/z/va9Yf1jzv I would have expected compilation to fail if (acc. to you comment) transform was 'return-by-value' when projection is 'return-by-reference' to a 'no-copy-no-move' type. Am I right?

Did you try to access the elements too? If it doesn't fail, then I need to refresh a bunch of things.

Element access compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/3qdEvPPdz. I do have issues with deducing the lambda parameter type (with auto) when using std::ranges::for_each, but that is another matter.
